# alternative to md5 (not for password hashing)

Tags: encryption, md5, renaming

so I want to generate some cached html files and I want to use some sort of encryption when naming them so they can't be easily accessed. Md5/Sha1,2 might be good alternatives but
I want something light something that would generate a string lets say 12 bytes long (just saying).

Is there anything similiar, available in php?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For obscurity through security purposes I would just use base64 or a simple random number based on seed, or a simple date maybe.
The thing is I don't see any cause for not using md5 as a performance hitter, though you can try crc32() which is basically a checksum calculator. If you insist on having anything else but sha1/md5 - you can also see this list here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hash-algos.php and use the hash() function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use uuid http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php to generate a unique name, but if you need to be able to reproduce the obfuscated name then your best bet is md5, speed shouldn't be an issue or whatever you refer to with "lightweight".

Answer (score 0):

For something simple, but low security, have a look at the appropriate sized [FNV hash](http://isthe.com/chongo/tech/comp/fnv/).  Once you have your hash as bytes, convert it to Base64 or whatever, as you wish.